# uri has type STRING rather than OBJECT in Scala and MongoDB integration?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, casbah, salat

I am working with Play framework(2.2.x) using Scala and MongoDB(v 2.6.11). I am trying to run sample application [using](https://github.com/NeelSachdeva/Play_Scala_MongoDB_Tutorial) in my system, as it is not executing the application and giving the compilation error in application.conf: `uri has type STRING rather than OBJECT`

application.conf:

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase"
```

Build.scala:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.0",
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.2",
    "com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.8",
    "org.mongodb" %% "casbah-gridfs" % "2.7.2",
    "se.radley" %% "play-plugins-salat" % "1.5.0"
```

Please let me know what is the mistake here and thanks for help in advance !

Comment: I'd need a stack trace to be able to debug.  However, you are mixing MongoDB Scala libraries which won't help.  As reactivemongo has good play integration and is asynchronous I'd recommend just using that library and removing the old casbah and salat versions.

Comment: @Ross, Yes, Thanks it is working fine with Reactive mongo. I have removed casbah and salat versions.

Comment: Just curious, did removing the explicit salat version and relying on transitive dependencies resolve your issue?